# MVC requests for /null returning 404 errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, null, http-status-code-404

I have an MVC project that appears to work great, unless you look at the error log. After every page is returned successfully, there is an attempt to load site.example.com/null and I have no idea why. Here's a snippet from Fiddler:

[image]

It has no effect to the user, but it is annoying. Here's a sample of the code that's being called:

```
public class GuidanceController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have nothing unusual in the view and I haven't had to change the RouteConfig. I do have a custom authorization class, like so:

```
namespace MyProj.Filters {
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]

public class MyProjAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AccessLvl[] AccessLvls;
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        AuthorizationClient authClient = new AuthorizationClient();
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
            return false;

        int intId = 0;
        string requestId = httpContext.Request.Path.Split('/').Last(); //get ID sent with new page
        string referrerId = httpContext.Request.UrlReferrer?.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last(); //get ID sent with old page

        if (int.TryParse(requestId, out intId) != true) //prefer new ID, if available
            int.TryParse(referrerId, out intId); //else just use old id

        List<AccessLvl> userAccessLevels = authClient.GetAccessLevels((intId == 0) ? null : intId.ToString());

        foreach (AccessLvl level in AccessLvls)
        {
            if (userAccessLevels.Contains(level))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    controller = "Error",
                    action = "Unauthorized",
                    urlReferrer = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url
                })
            );
    }
}
```

}

What am I overlooking? Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post your custom authorization class and view.Looks like there is a ajax call after your view is loaded

Comment: If the only thing that has changed is the custom authorization class, I would look there first. Post the code so we can at least rule it out. Can you create a new project with basic authorization and see if the behaviour persists?

Comment: @vamsi - I have added the code for the authorization class as requested. The only thing in the view is @{ ViewBag.Title = "Historical"; Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; } and two links. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Nick - I have added the code for the authorization class as requested.